# Handle multiple files in post request with Go

Tags: go, web, file-upload, webforms, server-side

I am using Go to write server-side for a music streaming service. I need to be able to handle album uploads. I want admins to be able to go to http://lisn.rocks/upload, select a folder that has to contain `meta.json`, `cover.jpg`, and some `.mp3` song files, click upload and the rest to be handled by server.

Here is a simple HTML page I'm using to test this functionality:

```html
<html>
    <head><title>Album Upload</title></head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="album" webkitdirectory directory multiple> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need a handler function that would be able to look at the `meta.json` file, check its contents and do stuff based on what's there. The `meta.json` contains all the info I need. Now, I don't need an extensive explanation about reading JSON with Go or other things that go along with it.

I just need to read all files from that folder as **separate** files. Instead, Go sees them all as a single `album` file field when I do `request.FormFile("album")`.

Answer (score 1):

Handling multiple files upload in go can be done by using the **MultipartForm** field of the request struct.

```
    multipartFormData := req.MultipartForm

    for _, v := range multipartFormData.File["attachments"] {
        fmt.Println(v.Filename, ":", v.Size)
        uploadedFile, _ := v.Open()
        // then use the single uploadedFile however you want
        // you may use its read method to get the file's bytes into a predefined slice, 
        //here am just using an anonymous slice for the example
        uploadedFile.Read([]byte{})
        uploadedFile.Close()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation for `FormFile` says, it only returns the first file. When the form is submitted, the `album` field will be an array and you have to use a multipart stream to process each individual file.

```
rd, err:=request.MultipartReader()
for {
  part, err:=rd.NextPart()
  if err==io.EOF {
      break
  }
  data,err:=ioutil.ReadAll(part)
  fileName:=part.FileName()
  part.Close()
}
```

You need to add error handling and data processing, etc.